# Multiple Inheritence in Python

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

I am starting to learn the Python language and need a critique of my code as well as solution to an error message I am getting.

The code creates a Robot class with two ancestors; Transformer and Gundam. A third class Hybrid inherits from these. I can instantiate a Transformer and a Gundam without error. 
Instantiating a Hybrid returns an error. Code and error follow below:

**Main.py**

```
from multiple_inheritance import Robot, Transformer, Gundam, Hybrid

tito = Gundam("Tito", "Japan")
optimus = Transformer("Optimus Prime", "Mars")
Jaeger = Hybrid("Striker", "US")

print(tito)
print(optimus)
```

**multiple_inheritance**

```
class Robot(object):
    """A robot class"""
    def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
            return "{name}".format(name = self.name)

class Transformer(Robot):
    """A transformer"""
    def __init__(self, name, planet):
            self.planet = planet
            super(Transformer, self).__init__(name)

    def __str__(self):
            return "Name = {name}, Planet = {planet}".\
                   format(name = self.name, planet = self.planet)

class Gundam(Robot):
    """A Gundam"""
    def __init__(self, name, country):
            self.country = country
            super(Gundam, self).__init__(name)

    def __str__(self):
            return "Name = {name}, Country = {country}".\
                   format(name = self.name, country = self.country)

class Hybrid(Transformer, Gundam):
    """Ultimate Robot"""
```

**Error Message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Tech\Python\my_code\unit10\multiple_inheritance_main.py", line 5, in <module>
    Jaeger = Hybrid("Striker", "US")
  File "D:\Tech\Python\my_code\unit10\multiple_inheritance.py", line 13, in __init__
    super(Transformer, self).__init__(name)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'country'
```

Comment: `Robot class with two ancestors` incorrect. In your code, `Robot` **is** the ancestor of both `Transformer` and `Gundam`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed in the other answer, Python builds a MRO (method resolution order) for your class, placing Hybrid->Transformer->Gundam->Robot  - that means not only that missing methods and attributes are searched in the classes in this order, but that is the order used when calling methods using the "super" construct.

I don't know of anyone ever saying multiple inheritance was "easy". It was even left altogether out of the Java language due to the complexities that arise. 
Python makes then usable with the "super" construct and the MRO concept - but if you 
need different keywords in the initializers of different superclasses, each class has to know how to deal with the arguements it does not know about.

So Hybrid is to be called with both a "name", a "country" and a "planet" argument - but Transformers don't know about "country", nor Gundams know about "planet".

In Python you can handle that using Keyword arguments - you have to make your intermediary classes accept all kinds of keyword arguments, and use the ones it knows about - in this case, it is as simply as changing the classes' `__init__` signature in this way, and make the proper adjust to the `super` calls:

```
class Robot(object):
    """A robot class"""
    def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
        ...

class Transformer(Robot):
    """A transformer"""
    def __init__(self, name, planet, **kwargs):
        ...      
        super(Transformer, self).__init__(name, **kwargs)

class Gundam(Robot):
    """A Gundam"""
    def __init__(self, name, country, **kwargs):
        ...      
        super(Gundam, self).__init__(name, **kwargs)
    ...
```

And of course, when instatiating an Hybrid, you now have
to name the parameters:

```
my_robot = Hybrid("XYZ-Star", planet="Earth", country="Japan")
```

Comment: You might want to have the `Transformer` and `Gundam` classes handle `name` as a keyword argument, since they don't use it themselves at all. That means, either use `name=name` when passing it on, or simply not taking it as a named parameter in the first place (so it will be part of `kwargs`).

Comment: @jsbueno Yes I agree with this post. The kwargs trick results in cleaner code with less chance of confusion by keeping mention of **Planet** out of the **Gundam Class** and **Country** out of the **Transformer Class**. All working now. I have added a '__str__' to **Hybrid"" 'class ---

Answer (score 4):

Hybrid's mro looks something like this:

```
>>> Hybrid.__mro__
(<class '__main__.Hybrid'>, <class '__main__.Transformer'>, <class '__main__.Gundam'>, <class '__main__.Robot'>, <type 'object'>)
```

As you can see after `Transformer` the next class is `Gundam` and you're not passing enough arguments to it when calling it from Transformer's `__init__`:

```
class Transformer(Robot):
    """A transformer"""
    def __init__(self, name, planet):
            self.planet = planet
            #####This calls Gundam's __init__
            super(Transformer, self).__init__(name)
```

So, the point is `super()` calls the next class in MRO not Transformer's base class as you expected.

---

A very good post related to `super()`: [Python’s super() considered super!](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

Comment: this makes things a bit complicated. `Transformer(Robot)` now calls `Gundam` as super? Then if you create a plain `Transformer`, how can you tell it which parent to call?

Comment: You don't - the MRO (method resolution order) does that for you. For a Plain transformer, the Transformer superclass is "Robot". The class hierarchy you created places Gundam between Transformer and Robot. Otherwise, which of the "super" calls would call's "Robot"'s `__init__` - the one in Transformer, or the one in Gundam?

Comment: @njzk2 Well `super()` is bit complicated, Yes for the current MRO super call from `Transformer` will call `Gundam`. I really don't understand your second question, the parent can be identified using the class's MRO.